# Do attack powers that have an effect of marking a target use the class's defender mark or some other version of a mark?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, mark, conditions

Do attack powers that have an effect of marking a target use the class's defender mark (e.g. Aegis of Assault) or some other version of a mark?

Powers like Swordmage: Dual Lightning Strike, lvl 3 encounter

the target of either attack on a hit is considered marked until the end of your next turn.
does this mean the targets are generically marked? or do they make use of the class's Aegis mark on these targets (until the end of your next turn)? if not the aegis then what are the conditions of the mark?

Considering the power is big on teleporting fair distances, and creating a fairly large control area it seems counter intuitive to say that such a power only provokes a generic, 'whilst in melee range' mark, but I'm hesitant to say otherwise.

Comment: To my despair, my epic paladin has *3* different kinds of marks, each with different triggers and punishments.

Answer (score 2):

[Dual Lightning Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=5743) reads:

> and the target is marked until the end of your next turn.

This is a normal mark.

If the intent had been to allow the use of the Aegis of Assault (or other aegis) mark punishment, then the power would have read, as [Swordmage Shielding Fire](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4800) does:

> and the creature is marked as if from your Swordmage Aegis power until the end of the encounter

Note that some defenders defenders have mark punishment that triggers just off the subject being marked.